# What is a Workman Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Workman Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Workman Words™ | Not Workman Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| LONE | WOLF |
| FUEL | TANK |
| PEE | URINE |
| FUNNY | JOKE |
| CONVEYING | FEELINGS |
| THRASH | BIN |
| ENJOY | LIFE |
| INVOKE | SPELL |
| STRAW | LAST |
| HARD | CORE |

The CSV version:

```
Workman Words™,Not Workman Words™
LONE,WOLF
FUEL,TANK
PEE,URINE
FUNNY,JOKE
CONVEYING,FEELINGS
THRASH,BIN
ENJOY,LIFE
INVOKE,SPELL
STRAW,LAST
HARD,CORE
```

These are not the only examples of Workman Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe...

> They're words that can be typed on keys **touching one another** in a Workman keyboard layout (Pic from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Workman)):
>
>  [image]
>
>  In contrast, all the non-Workman words don't form an unbroken line on it.